# Tkinter Button background - white only on a mac (10.15.4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, button, tkinter

I don't think this is a coding issue, but I would be grateful for some clues.

I have some code which turns Tkinter Buttons green or red as they control relays.  This works fine on my RaspberryPi but I cannot get any Button background colour except white on my code writing machine a MacPro.  I am running Python 3.7.3 and Pycharm 2019.3.4 on both.  Raspberian (latest release can’t remember version number) and OSX 10.15.4 on the Mac.

When I run from Pycharm, colour can be set for the Window background (e.g. red) and text (Button foreground), but no matter what way (e.g. bg=’red’ or background=’blue’)the Button remains white.  If I run from a command prompt the Window background colour can be set red but the Button remains white and this time the text stays black.   As I say if I run the same simplified pf file on the RaspberryPi all the colours are fine.

Any clue would be very much appreciated thank you, stay safe

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
try:
    # for Python2
    from Tkinter import *   ## notice capitalized T in Tkinter
except ImportError:
    # for Python3
    from tkinter import *   ## notice lowercase 't' in tkinter here

Root=Tk()
Root.geometry('300x450')
Root.config(background = "red")

Btn1=Button(Root, text="Where is the Green background ?", background='green', foreground='blue').pack()
Btn2 = Button(Root, text = 'No red background', bg='red', fg='blue').pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Possibly a bug in the Mac implementation of tkinter.

Comment: Thank you, strange no one else has come across it.  I can't find anything on WWW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with tkinter and python 3.73. Works fine with Python 3.72 but not 3.73. I got this info about tkinter from the instructions for [Simple_GUI,](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thank you, I was OK coding and running with Python and Python3, but I've just spent a very confusing hour trying to figure out how to run code in a specific subversion i.e. 3.7.2 or 3.8.2.  I have read the link and I think you are right but I'm either a) don't worry about it as it runs on the target Pi, b) switch to Kivy or c) not bother with that as the code is eventually going to be a webapp.........   Thank you for taking the time to answer me