# the text in the Button function doesn't appear in my phyton Tkinter. I'm using a MacBooks. anyone has any idea how to fix my code?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

can someone help me ou. I couldn't seem to figure out why the button's text doesn't appear on my interface window. im using a Mac OS. 
'''

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title("Simple Calculator")

e = Entry(root, width=35, borderwidth= 5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

def button_add():
    return


button_1 = Button(root, text= "1",fg="red", padx = 40, pady =20, command=button_add)


button_2 = Button(root, text= "2", fg="red",padx = 40, pady =20, command=button_add)


button_3 = Button(root, text= "3", fg="red",padx = 40, pady =20, command=button_add)


button_4 = Button(root, text= "4", fg="red",padx = 40, pady =20, command=button_add)


button_5 = Button(root, text= "5",fg="red", padx = 40, pady =20, command=button_add)


button_6 = Button(root, text= "6", fg="red",padx = 40, pady =20, command=button_add)


button_7 = Button(root, text= "7", fg="red",padx = 40, pady =20, command=button_add)


button_8 = Button(root, text= "8", fg="red",padx = 40, pady =20, command=button_add)


button_9 = Button(root, text= "9",fg="red", padx = 40, pady =20, command=button_add)

# put buttons on the screen

button_1.grid(row= 3, column=0)

button_2.grid(row= 3, column=1)
button_3.grid(row= 3, column=2)

button_4.grid(row=2 , column=0)
button_5.grid(row= 2, column=1)
button_6.grid(row= 2, column=2)

button_7.grid(row= 1, column=0)
button_8.grid(row= 1, column=1)
button_9.grid(row= 1, column=2)



root.mainloop()
```

'''

please help. I don't know why the button's text doesn't appear on the interface window. it only appears as white.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter Button background - white only on a mac (10.15.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61015257/tkinter-button-background-white-only-on-a-mac-10-15-4)

Answer (score -1):

There are many syntax error in your program.
for eg  the correct syntax for Button is `button_1 = tkinter.Button(root, text='1')`
kindy go thru the documentation of tkinter.

Note: you program have many indentation warning of unnecessary spaces. kindly work on that.

Try the below code.

```
try:
    import tkinter
except ImportError:     # for python 2 user
    import Tkinter as tkinter


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Simple Calculator")
e = tkinter.Entry(root, width=35, borderwidth= 5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)


def button_add():
    return


button_1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="1",fg="red", padx=40, pady=20, command=button_add)
button_2 = tkinter.Button(root, text="2", fg="red", padx=40, pady=20, command=button_add)
button_3 = tkinter.Button(root, text="3", fg="red", padx=40, pady=20, command=button_add)
button_4 = tkinter.Button(root, text="4", fg="red", padx =40, pady=20, command=button_add)
button_5 = tkinter.Button(root, text="5", fg="red", padx=40, pady=20, command=button_add)
button_6 = tkinter.Button(root, text="6", fg="red", padx=40, pady=20, command=button_add)
button_7 = tkinter.Button(root, text="7", fg="red", padx=40, pady=20, command=button_add)
button_8 = tkinter.Button(root, text="8", fg="red", padx=40, pady=20, command=button_add)
button_9 = tkinter.Button(root, text="9", fg="red", padx=40, pady=20, command=button_add)

# put buttons on the screen

button_1.grid(row=3, column=0)
button_2.grid(row=3, column=1)
button_3.grid(row=3, column=2)

button_4.grid(row=2 , column=0)
button_5.grid(row=2, column=1)
button_6.grid(row=2, column=2)

button_7.grid(row=1, column=0)
button_8.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_9.grid(row=1, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried this. and it worked just nicely. I will try to fix my code and make it cleaner. thanks for this great suggestion!